# Why I cannot use string methods inside groovy closure? - no candidate for method call

Tags: string, groovy, closures

I have simple hashmap and want to manipulate it but IDE does not recognize the methods. Completely new to Groovy so not sure what is wrong.

```
    def percentages = [
        "x1" : "20%",
        "x2" : "30%",
        "x3" : "0.4",
        "x4" : "50%",
        "x5" : "0.6"]

    percentages.each {
    val ->
         if(val[2].endsWith("%")) {
        val[2].deleteCharAt(val.length()-1)
        println val
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `percentages.each` you iterate over map and each element is `java.util.Map.Entry`. Here is probably what you need:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry

def percentages = [
    "x1": "20%",
    "x2": "30%",
    "x3": "0.4",
    "x4": "50%",
    "x5": "0.6"]

percentages.each { Entry<String, String> val ->
    if (val.value.endsWith("%")) {
        val.value = val.value.substring(0, val.value.length() - 1)
        println val
    }
}
```

or even more compact, as @daggett suggested:

```
def percentages = [
    "x1": "20%",
    "x2": "30%",
    "x3": "0.4",
    "x4": "50%",
    "x5": "0.6"]

percentages.each {k, v ->
    if (v.endsWith("%")) {
        percentages[k] = v.substring(0, v.length() - 1)
        println percentages[k]
    }
}
```

Comment: true, facepalm. Thank you very much!

Comment: Or `percentages.each{k,v-> ...}`